# how to find avg of column of csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

```
import csv
with open('Met.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

I am not able to go ahead how to get a column from the csv file I tried

```
print row[:column_name]

name    id  name    reccla  mass (g)    fall    year    GeoLocation

Aachen  1       Valid   L5   21     Fell    01/01/1880 (50.775000, 6.083330)    
Aarhus  2       Valid   H6  720     Fell    1/1/1951  (53.775000, 6.586560)
Abee    6       Valid   EH4 --      Fell    1/1/1952 (50.775000, 6.083330)  
Acapul  10      Valid   A   353      Fell   1/1/1952  (50.775000, 6.083330)
Acapul  1914    valid   A    --      Fell   1/1/1952 (50.775000, 6.083330)
AdhiK   379    Valid    EH4 56655    Fell   1/1/1919 (50.775000, 6.083330)
```

and I want avg of mass (g)

Comment: What is the structure of your `csv` file?

Comment: name id nametype    recclass      mass  
Aarhus 2 Valid     H6       720
Abee 6 Valid    EH4      107000
Acapulco 10 Valid    Acapulcoite 914
Achiras 370 Valid    L6      780
Adhi Kot 379 Valid EH4 4239
Adzhi        390 Valid LL3-6 910
Agen 392 Valid H5 30000

Comment: please add data to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `pandas` instead of reading from `csv`

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Met.csv')
```

It is far easier to grab columns and perform operations using `pandas`.
Here I am loading the csv contents to a dataframe.

**Loaded data :** (*sample data*)

```
>>> data
       name   id nametype     recclass    mass
0    Aarhus    2    Valid           H6     720
1      Abee    6    Valid          EH4  107000
2  Acapulco   10    Valid  Acapulcoite     914
3   Achiras  370    Valid           L6     780
4  Adhi Kot  379    Valid          EH4    4239
5     Adzhi  390    Valid        LL3-6     910
6      Agen  392    Valid           H5   30000
```

**Just the Mass column :**

You can access individual columns as data['column name']

```
>>> data['mass']
0       720
1    107000
2       914
3       780
4      4239
5       910
6     30000
Name: mass, dtype: int64
```

**Average of Mass column :**

```
>>> data['mass'].mean()
20651.857142857141
```

Comment: is there any limitation on pandas regarding number of lines in file because my file contains ~4000  values and its not able to print when I am try to check it fro print

Comment: 4000 should be ok. pandas can handle easily

Comment: I got errors |||1-- return self._getitem_column(key)                                   || 2--in _get_item_cache values = self._data.get(item)
||3--- in get loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
||4--- get_loc return self._engine.get_loc(key)
||5-- pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3979)
||6-- is there any limitation on pandas regarding number of lines in file because my file contains ~4000  values and its not able to print when I am try to check it fro print

Comment: i am trying if possible please see the errors thanks for help @astrosyam

Comment: @HariRama at this point it would be best if you could provide a small subset of your data that demonstrates this (along with the offending code). Please edit your original question.

Comment: I think now its clear, if there is null value then it might create problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv.DictReader()` instead of `csv.reader()`. The following code works fine to me

```
import csv

mass_list = []
with open("../data/Met.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        mass = row["mass"]
        if mass is not None and mass is not "--":
            mass_list.append(float(row["mass"]))

avg_mass = sum(mass_list) / len(mass_list)
print "avg of mass: ", avg_mass
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but it is not working, could u see the edited file. still should this work?

Comment: Seems there are some missing values in your file. You can add some check before compute the average. See the updated code for details.

Comment: you are correct there is missing values but data this this only

Comment: @HariRama Thus you can add code to verify whether it is a missing value or not.