# How to sum values from a row, or a column from a csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, sum, row

Could someone help me out to understand how python sum values from a row and also from a column, the second I believe that I have figured out still I have not grasp the concept so far, once I will be able to assign values, sum, filter to a variable I can move forward to visualisation.

[image: Like sum the 1948 row and so on]
File
Year Jan  Fev  Mar ... Annual
1948 4.0  4.7  4.5 ...  3.8
1949 5.0  5.8  5.6 ...  5.9
...

```
with open('unemployment1948.csv', 'r') as unFile:
        unReader = csv.DictReader(unFile, delimiter = ',')
        unHeads = unReader.fieldnames
        print(unHeads)

        u = defaultdict(float)
        for r in unReader:
            for v in r['Year']:
                try:
                    d[r['1948']] += float(v)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        print(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` seems to be the 'go to' tool for work like this in Python.

Looks like you have a DataFrame so with `pandas` you should be able to do something like:

```
df.sum(axis = 0)
```

where `axis=0` will return values for months and

```
df.sum(axis = 1)
```

will return values for the years.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056012/how-to-find-avg-of-column-of-csv-file) also has some examples as well as the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) themselves.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying with DictReader caused it was an exercise, once I understood the concept I just rather use pandas.
i got it, I found another way using your suggestion.

    {df = pd.read_csv('unemployment1948.csv', delimiter = ',', 
    index_col = 'Year')
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    df.head()

    df.sum(axis = 1)
    y48 = df.loc[1948]
    sY48 = sum(y48[1:12])
    sY48}